# jquery few images change to other image with fade effect

Tags: jquery

I got one link, and few different images.
 When I press on this link, I want that this few images, change to other images with fade effect (every single image has its own image on a replacement), how can do it with jQuery or Javascript, or maybe there is some scripts :)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try [Jquery cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plugin, specifically [here](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/pager3.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, this one does not fit my needs